# Does flutter_bloc dispose of the cubit if you specify the bloc in the BlocBuilder?

Tags: flutter

I've seen `BlocProvider` automatically disposes of the bloc in the `flutter_bloc` package. Is this also the case when specifying the bloc/cubit scoped to a single widget?

```
BlocBuilder<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  cubit: blocA, // provide the local cubit instance
  builder: (context, state) {
    // return widget here based on BlocA's state
  }
)
```

(I seem to be creating multiply instances of my cubit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BlocBuilder` has nothing to do with dispose of a bloc instance. It is `BlocProvider`, that takes care of it automatically. The only case, when you have to dispose of a bloc instance manually, is when you provide it to next widget tree with `BlocProvider.value`.